# Weird behavior in vue/vuetify attribute binding with template literals

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, template-literals

I tried to feet the v-treeview component in vuetify with an object, wrapped in an array, as an template literal.

```
<template lang="pug">
v-container.media-lib-container
  v-treeview(:items="[media]" dense)
  v-btn(@click="test") test
</template>
```

The page is loading normal but when I try to open the tree view, I get an type error in vuetify.js.

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'vnode' of undefined
>
> > at VueComponent.register (vuetify.js?ce5b:30786)

Weirdly when I compute the data, and return it as an template literal it works fine.

```
  computed: {
    mediaArr() {
      return [this.media];
    },
  },
```

Does anyone know if this is a bug or if I miss something? and if this is caused by vue or by vuetify?

I think I know at least where my problem hides.
I get my object from npm directory-tree module and than add an id property to every child for the v-treeview. Also it stopped working again(maybe never has).

The original json:

```
{
  "path": "../uploads",
  "name": "uploads",
  "children": [
    { "path": "../uploads/parsed", "name": "parsed", "children": [], "size": 0, "type": "directory" },
    {
      "path": "../uploads/test",
      "name": "test",
      "children": [
        { "path": "../uploads/test/test2", "name": "test2", "children": [], "size": 0, "type": "directory" }
      ],
      "size": 0,
      "type": "directory"
    },
    {
      "path": "../uploads/uploads",
      "name": "uploads",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": "../uploads/uploads/public",
          "name": "public",
          "children": [
            {
              "path": "../uploads/uploads/public/projectA",
              "name": "projectA",
              "children": [],
              "size": 0,
              "type": "directory"
            },
            {
              "path": "../uploads/uploads/public/projectB",
              "name": "projectB",
              "children": [],
              "size": 0,
              "type": "directory"
            }
          ],
          "size": 0,
          "type": "directory"
        }
      ],
      "size": 0,
      "type": "directory"
    }
  ],
  "size": 0,
  "type": "directory"
}
```

The parsed object with the added id:

```
        path: "../uploads",
        name: "uploads",
        children: [
          {
            path: "../uploads/parsed",
            name: "parsed",
            children: [],
            size: 0,
            type: "directory",
            id: 1,
          },
          {
            path: "../uploads/test",
            name: "test",
            children: [
              {
                path: "../uploads/test/test2",
                name: "test2",
                children: [],
                size: 0,
                type: "directory",
                id: 3,
              },
            ],
            size: 0,
            type: "directory",
            id: 2,
          },
          {
            path: "../uploads/uploads",
            name: "uploads",
            children: [
              {
                path: "../uploads/uploads/public",
                name: "public",
                children: [
                  {
                    path: "../uploads/uploads/public/projectA",
                    name: "projectA",
                    children: [],
                    size: 0,
                    type: "directory",
                    id: 6,
                  },
                  {
                    path: "../uploads/uploads/public/projectB",
                    name: "projectB",
                    children: [],
                    size: 0,
                    type: "directory",
                    id: 7,
                  },
                ],
                size: 0,
                type: "directory",
                id: 5,
              },
            ],
            size: 0,
            type: "directory",
            id: 4,
          },
        ],
        size: 0,
        type: "directory",
        id: 0,
      },
```

The code in mounted to add id:

```
  mounted() {
    let id = 0;
    function recur(obj) {
      obj.id = id;
      ++id;
      obj.children.map((child) => recur(child));
    }
    recur(this.media);
  },
```

The thing I don't understand is, that when I console.log(JSON.stringify(this.media) and put it directly in vue data it works. Both as a template literal in the attribute binding and as computed.

Comment: How does `media` look?

Comment: Ok I found the problem, stupid me. I use nuxt and when I make it client only it works fine. So it has something to do with the server side rendering. Sorry but still thanks. Nice wasted 2 hours. I will edit my question or shoud I delete it? It's kinda useless now.